# Correct syntax for importing axios method in Vue js

Tags: javascript, promise, vuejs2, axios

I am trying to separate my axios calls from my main vue instance by importing them instead of calling them directly in the created hook.

I have this in a separate file called data.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
export default{
    myData() {
        return axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/data.json`)
            .then(response => {
                // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
                return response.data;
            })
            .catch(e => {
                return this.myErrors.push(e)
            });
},
```

And in my vue instance I have the following:

```
import myDataApi from '@/api/data.js'

export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: {
        myDataApi, // not sure if this is correct
    },
    data: function () {
        return {
            myInfo: '',
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.myInfo = myDataApi.myData();
        console.log('this.myInfo= ', this.myInfo)
    },
```

I am trying to populate myInfo with the json called by myData. This returns `[object Promise]` in Vue devtools and the as `Promise {<pending>}` in the console.

All the data I need is inside that `Promise {<pending>}` in an array called `[[PromiseValue]]:Object` so I know it is working, I just need to know the correct way implementing this.

Comment: This is the nature of promises. It's pending because by the time you log it the axios-request hasn't completed. The first thing you try is to unwrap your data from your promise, but realize that is not the problem. The promise solves the problem of knowing when the data is available. You can do additional modifications to the value, like `this.myInfo = myDataApi.myData().then(r=>r.a = b);` but the promise stays. However, you can bind it directly to your template as is and the value will show up when loaded, so it's not the problem you may think it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have a development environment enabled to test this at the moment, but I do notice that you are trying to assign a variable the moment that the component is initialized. This object is a promise, but you're not handling the promise after it is resolved inside the component where you have imported it.

I would recommend trying to handle the promise inside of the actual component, something like:

```
import myDataApi from '@/api/data.js'

export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: {
        myDataApi, // not sure if this is correct
    },
    data: function () {
        return {
            myInfo: '',
        }
    },
    created() {
        myDataApi.myData()
          .then((data) => {
            this.myInfo = data
            console.log('this.myInfo= ', this.myInfo);
          });
          .catch((e) => handleError) // however you want to handle it

    },
```

Comment: I'm also not familiar with the view api, so you will have to adapt the above to the proper syntax, but what I am more certain of is that you are going to handle the promise inside the important component.

Comment: Thanks so much for explaining that. Cheers

Comment: `myDataApi, // not sure if this is correct` Right now you are treating it like a normal import so yeah, you can safely remove this so called "component" from components.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to @LexJacobs answer. I omitted the parenthesis around data in .then() as seen below. Vue was squawking about data not being available even though it was. This solved that problem, although to be honest I don't know why.

```
myDataApi.myData()
    .then(data => {
        this.dataHasLoaded = true;
        this.myInfo = data;
    })
    .catch(e => {
        this.myErrors.push(e)
    });
```